# awk printf 'duplicates' line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf, gzip

I'm trying to merge some files in a single file with awk and printf

```
File1, File2 ... MergedFile
```

The contents of the files are with a lot of input but what I am interested in are events so e.g.

```
File1:
...
event#          1 ...
...
event#          2 ...
```

The format is specific and I would like to keep it while modifying all events in subsequent files based on their number

```
File2:
event#          1 becomes event#          3
event#          2 becomes event#          4
...
```

So far I managed to do that using

```
awk -v nev="$NEV" '/event#/{printf "%6s %9u\n", $1, $2+=nev}1' input > output
```

where NEV is the number of events per file

However, my problem is that this does what I want it to but adds a duplicate line like so

```
      MergedFile:
        ...
        event#          1 ...
        event# 1...
        ...
        event#          2 ...
        event# 2...
        ...
        event#          3 ...
        event# 3...
        ...
        event#          4 ...
        event# 4...
        ...
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the problem is fixed.
Performance is the new issue.
I added `$1=event#` but it is still slow. Any ideas how to optimize?

Also there is the space problem, the merged file becomes quite large and post merging I gzip it, however the disk I am using may not have sufficient space to hold the uncompressed file.

Comment: Remove the `1` from the end of your code. It causes the line to be printed again.

Comment: You are correct, however removing the 1, removes all other text before and after lines containing event#

Comment: Replace it with `!/event#/`, then. Or put `next` after the printf.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. Using !/event#/ leaves me with lines with spaces and 0s  corresponding to the deleted strings and numbers
               0                       0                                                              0.000.

Comment: I meant to replace the `1` with `!/event#/`. But `next` after `printf` is better (less repetitive).

Comment: One of you two should add an answer so this question has some value. @HERDER, http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing 1 with `!/event#/` fixes the problem.
Thanks to @Wintermute